# Matplotlib removing white border(padding) when .set_aspect = 'equal'

Tags: python, matplotlib

in matplotlib the set_aspect('equal') settings overrides the padding(white border) settings. As a result the output is a square boxed filled with whitespace. How do I override this behavior, so that the set_aspect setting only applies to the contourf plot and not the entire output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
```

or

```
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,30,cmap=plt.cm.jet,antialiased=True,alpha=0.4,norm=c_scale,aspect='equal')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axes.set_aspect function sets the plotting area aspect. If you want the output (image or figure) have different height, width, take a look at the [matplotlib.figure.Figure](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.figure.Figure)  arguments or [matplotlib.figure.savefig](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig).

Answer (score 1):

When you save your file, you should use

`plt.savefig("out.png", bbox_inches="tight")`